# help modifying picoUPS

Tags: ups

I found a simple commercially available uninterruptable power supply [picoUPS-100](http://www.mini-box.com/picoUPS-100-12V-DC-micro-UPS-system-battery-backup-system). The manufacturer does not provide the circuit schematic, however, the principle block diagram looks like that:
[image]

I would like to to use it my car along with a small battery. It looks like the battery would be charging without control, so if I do not drive often, the charger will drain the car's battery eventually. I was hoping that it would not be difficult to add a logical charge_Enable switch to the device to only allow the charging portion of the device work when the ignition is ON. To achieve that I would like to place a MOSFET [FDD6630A](http://www.promelec.ru/pdf/FDD6630A.pdf) instead of the Diode, and connect the gate to the 12V ignition signal to serve as the gate drive:

[image]

Please, let me know your thoughts on this:

1. Does it look reasonable from the functional diagram perspective?
2. Do I need a pull down resistor for the gate?
3. Shouldn't the connections for drains and sources be reversed?

Comment: What kind of "car" are you talking about here?

Comment: @duskwuff honda civic

Comment: What sort of device are you powering in the car? Is there any reason you can't power it directly from the car's 12V?

Comment: They make [a model for car applications](http://www.mini-box.com/picoUPS-120-12V-DC-micro-UPS-battery-backup?sc=8&category=980). If you power the circuit through a fuse from the only-on-when-the-car-is-on supply, you won't drain the car battery.

Comment: @AndrewMorton That's weird.... I actually contacted them, but they did not offer me any other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The manual says the unit operates from a 15 - 18 volt input, and that the battery charger will not work if the input is below 15 volts - doesn't sound suitable for car use to me.

Comment: I read the manual. It does say that it can operate as low as 6V, and if the voltage is below 15V, it will not be able to "fully" charge the battery. Well, that's why I wanted to get an opinion if it would be practically acceptable.